# Difficulty comparators do not seem to affect the solver

Tags: optaplanner

I'm trying to add a difficulty comparator to an entity class (`Lecture`) so that the hardest-to-schedule lectures gets scheduled first.

My setup is as follows:

- `Lecture` has `startTimeslot` and `room` planning variables

  - both are `nullable = true`
- I have no construction heuristic, only local search
- Very simple configuration:

  ```
  <localSearch>
      <termination>
          <unimprovedSecondsSpentLimit>300</unimprovedSecondsSpentLimit>
      </termination>
      <changeMoveSelector>
          <filterClass>my.solver.PinnedTimeslotChangeMoveFilter</filterClass>
      </changeMoveSelector>
      <acceptor>
          <entityTabuSize>7</entityTabuSize>
      </acceptor>
      <forager>
          <acceptedCountLimit>1000</acceptedCountLimit>
      </forager>
  </localSearch>
  ```
- I have also tried adding this to the `changeMoveSelector`:

  ```
  <entitySelector>
      <cacheType>STEP</cacheType>
      <selectionOrder>SORTED</selectionOrder>
      <sorterManner>DECREASING_DIFFICULTY</sorterManner>
  </entitySelector>
  ```
- I have tried using a `difficultyWeightFactoryClass` instead to no avail.
- The `Lecture` planning entity has the following annotation:

  ```
  @PlanningEntity(difficultyComparatorClass = LectureDifficultyComparator.class)
  public class Lecture {
      ...
  }
  ```
- The `LectureDifficultyComparator` looks as follows (for the sake of just getting this to work):

  ```
  public class LectureDifficultyComparator implements Comparator<Lecture> {

      Comparator<Lecture> comparator = Comparator.comparing(
          l -> l.getDisplayName().startsWith("HARD_") ? 1 : 0);

      @Override
      public int compare(Lecture o1, Lecture o2) {
          return comparator.compare(o1, o2);
      }
  }
  ```

I'm looking at the scheduling as it discovers new best solutions, and it rarely schedules the hard lectures first. In fact, it makes no difference if I change `compare(o1, o2)` to `compare(o2, o1)`.

Thoughts:

- I know that the difficulty is a "hint" to the solver, and that some algorithms even ignores it. Have I accidentally managed to chose such an algorithm?
- Does it matter that my planning variables are `nullable`? Does this mean that they are considered "uninitialized" and that difficulty is thus disregarded somehow?
- What's the best way to debug this? Is there some particular logging output I can enable to see how OptaPlanner "thinks"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, none of the available Local Search algorithms is able to take advantage of [planning entity difficulty comparison](https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/planner-configuration/planner-configuration.html#planningEntityDifficulty).

The entity difficulty comparison can only be used in Exhaustive Search and in Construction Heuristic phase by the `DECREASING` variants of First Fit, Weakest Fit, and Strongest Fit algorithms.

What you're trying to do is simply not possible in the Local Search phase.

I would recommend you to try the Construction Heuristic phase. It might be a bit tricky to use it correctly with [nullable planning variables](https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/planner-configuration/planner-configuration.html#nullablePlanningVariable) but if you get it to work, it will give you a huge score boost.

By not using CH, you're "misusing" the LS to initialize the solution, which is not its purpose (LS is good at improving solutions).

Use CH before LS to give LS a much better starting point (in terms of score) in very little time (CH is designed to find a good initial solution quickly).

Comment: Thanks yurloc. That's obviously quite valuable information 